# Speed up MySQL query with multiple joins

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my issue, I am selecting and doing multiple joins to get the correct item.

Anyone know how I can speed this up? It takes around 19 seconds?

**Here is the query.**

```
    SELECT
      t1.id AS HostingID,
      t5.date_id AS DateRelid
    FROM
      tblhosting AS t1
      INNER JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.relid
      INNER JOIN tblcustomfields AS t3 ON t2.fieldid = t3.id
      INNER JOIN tbl_course AS t4 ON t1.packageid = t4.course_pid
      INNER JOIN tbl_dates AS t5 ON t4.course_title = t5.date_coursetitle
    WHERE
      t3.fieldname LIKE "%Course Date%" AND
      t1.id = "$hostingid" AND
      t1.userid = "$userid" AND
      t5.date_coursedisplay = t2.value AND
      t5.date_courselocation = t4.course_location
    ORDER BY t5.date_id DESC
      LIMIT 0 , 1
```

I am not the greatest with mysql so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

An Explain Of My SQL :

```
id  select_type     table     type    possible_keys                        key            key_len     ref                           rows     Extra   
1   SIMPLE           t1       const   PRIMARY,serviceid,userid,productid   PRIMARY        4           const                         1        Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE           t5       ALL     NULL                                 NULL           NULL        NULL                          20744   
1   SIMPLE           t3       ALL     PRIMARY                              NULL           NULL        NULL                          4101     Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE           t2       ref     fieldid_relid                        fieldid_relid   8          nextstep_next.t3.id,const     1        Using where
1   SIMPLE           t4       ALL     NULL                                 NULL           NULL        NULL                          664      Using where; Using join buffer
```

Comment: Could you provide some more info : the structure of your tables, the approximate number of rows in each ?

Comment: `t1 -  id  userid  orderid  packageid  server  regdate - 16000 rows`
`t2 -  fieldid  relid  value - 80,000 Rows`
`t3 -   id  type  relid  fieldname  fieldtype  description  fieldoptions  regexpr  adminonly  required  showorder  showinvoice  sortorde - 5000 rows`
`t4 -  Full texts  course_id  course_title  course_location  course_pid  course_venue  course_note - 500 rows`
`t5 -  Full texts  date_id  date_select  date_courselocation  date_coursetitle  date_coursedisplay - 21,000 rows` @Loufylouf hope this helps, its a WHMCS database with custom tables

Comment: A readable format would be way better than this. Like a properly indented `CREATE TABLE`, that would give us the different types of your columns as well as a way to quickly create your tables for testing. And such an information is really important, so it would be better to add it to your question than here in the comments.

Comment: Without further table information it's impossible to give the right answer. You could try adding an index to table tbl_dates as your explain shows no key can be used.

Comment: remove the like condition and see if that speeds it up, if so then there's your bottleneck.

Comment: but first add those indexes to coursedisplay and courselocation in tbl_dates

Comment: This bit cannot use an index, so will be slow : `LIKE "%Course Date%" `

Answer (score 0):

I think clarification on the indexes would help.  It is still quite brief on context to confirm.  I suggest the following indexes to help optimize.

```
Table                 index
tblHosting            ( id, userid, packageid )
tblcustomfieldsvalues ( relid, fieldid, value )
tblcustomfields       ( id, fieldname )
tbl_course            ( course_pid )
tbl_dates             ( date_coursetitle, date_courselocation, date_coursedisplay )
```

At least with your tblcustomfields table, it can be partially optimized via the ID column first, THEN the field name.

Most of these indexes are covering indexes meaning it does not have to go back to the raw data pages to complete the join, it can grab all the data from the indexes directly.